# Slow Start on 12V DC Motor

Tags: dc-motor, buck-boost, hobbyist

I am designing a small mechanical device that makes use of a 12VDC motor. I am trying to stick with components that can be easily sourced from Amazon or other hobby electronics stores so that others can build it themselves. I also chose to power the device with micro usb using a [boost converter circuit board](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08R5LMQH1) to get to the required 12V so users can just use a standard USB wall charger instead of having to use a dedicated 12V power supply.

I need a decent amount of torque at about 1000 rpm that can easily fit in a small space. Initially, I went with this somewhat ubiquitous [N20 geared motor](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08BZC7Y1Z), but found the tiny gears were quickly wearing to the point of failure. Now, I’ve opted for the larger [25GA370 geared motor](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07JFF3TH9). Strangely, for about half a second after I switch the device on, the new motor spins at about half of its rated RPM before suddenly jumping to full speed.

One potential explanation for this is the boost converter module I’m using limits the output current to 2A, which is just shy of the <2.1A start/stall current advertised for this motor. My expectation was that the motor wouldn’t start at all if this was the issue. Or if it did start, that it would gradually ramp up to the rated speed. In any case, I was wondering if there was a simple explanation for the slow start followed by the sudden jump?

Comment: "the boost converter module I’m using limits the output current to 2A"  really? most boost converters are rated by input current

Comment: The Amazon listing I linked specifies maximum output current of 2A in the 3rd product image. Other sellers use similar language.

Comment: The thing about amazon is it's full of vendors who don't know what they're selling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a boost converter has an inductor and a diode between the input and the output, When the converter quits because overcurrent you'll get about
4.5V on the converter output until it restarts.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1SmK6.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The 4.5V will give a little over one third speed

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, this makes perfect sense. If this behavior works for my use case, would continuing to use the boost converter in this way to kick start my motor lead to premature failure?

Comment: it's hard to guess. if that's a 5A (input) boost converter you're probably fine.

Comment: The max current rating for micro-usb is 2A. How can I determine the current at the input side of the boost converter when it drops to 4.5V on the output? If it is anywhere close to 5A, it sounds like I should not be trying to run this motor off of usb.

Comment: I think this is the chip https://www.olimex.com/Products/Breadboarding/BB-PWR-3608/resources/MT3608.pdf  it says "2A" and "4A" I'm not sure which of those is the input current limit.